# filter data in django model form factory

Tags: python, django

i am new in django, try to put a dropdown from the given model,

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel)
    account_type = models.CharField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE, max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'hotel'),)
```

i.e trying to create dropdown of `name` field values but per hotel wise,see there is a foreign field `hotel`,

initially my view was something like this(not aware of having hotel wise `name` field value in drop down)

```
@staff_only
def account_list(request, hotel):
    form = modelform_factory(Account, exclude=['hotel'])()
    return render(request, 'pms/domains.html', {'hotel': hotel,'form': form, 'page': 'account'})
```

here i have used `modelform_factory` and its returning `name` field values of all hotel,but i need a **hotel wise** filtered drop down of `name` field values. i don't find any way to filter data here(per hotel wise) in modelform_factory.So i have decided to use **django model form**. Is there any way to filter data using django model form?

Comment: Does `name` refer to the names of the hotels (which feels duplicated by the way)? What do you mean by `hotel wise filtered`. `hotel` is a ForeignKey, so there is only one hotel per `Account`.

Comment: no `name` refer to the account name i.e (sales, staff salary etc) and under a hotel, there can be multiple Account object.So i just want to show a dropdown of a `name` values of a certain hotel not all hotel. @arie